# Remove underscores from page links in browsing bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I came up with problem that to make good SEO there can't be underscores in links. I have project runing Ruby On Rails 3.
So I now wonder how it is posible to remove them and/or replace them with dashes.

I tried to search for this Q but there apeared just answers that are related to CSS. Like removing underscore from links.

**Here is  part of my routes file.**

```
root :to => "home#index"

devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config 
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|lv|ru/ do   
        resources :products,:waste_equipment,:sitemap,:energy, :energy_wood_machinery,:fuel_tanks, :soil_equipment,:soil, :tractors_and_loaders,:support_for_sport,:search,:location,:used_items,:admin_users,:conditions, :details,:projects,:knives,:messages, :mails, :photos,:emilianaserbatoi_products, :send_email_us,:subscribes, :home,:manufacturers, :location, :categories, :news, :manufacturer_products, :about_us,:contacts, :services, :partners 
  end
```

I wonder, that can be done using routes file or some gem is necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: Solution: resources "waste-equipment", :controller => :waste_equipment, :as => :waste_equipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you suggest in your comment, but you must not do it at once because you 'll end up with all your previous link invalidated and that is the SEO equivalent of shooting your leg.

you should:

- add the new rules as an extra set of rules
- log legacy link access
- provide `moved_permanently` status code ([301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)) for redirecting from old routes to new
- a while after your logs are empty from legacy links remove them from google admin tools and update the routes